# Java Strings Type Array or Simple String usage

Tags: java, arrays, string

i am beginner  in java and  want to ask  a basic question

While reading  Strings and Arrays i came to see sometimes we use    String Type Arras like this

```
String   Words[]={"first ", "Second"..};
String  words="These are sample words";
```

and some more ways to declare it  . I want to ask that  what is the basic  difference between  the two mentioned  Strings .. i mean  why we  need to declare String Type  Array   instead of  `String  obj= ..;` etc .  Can someone please explain

Comment: They ARE different. One is array to multiple String objects, the other is a single String object.

Comment: `what is the basic difference` -> Why are you trying to compare Water, and Water container?

Comment: @RohitJain  i have been using both of them ,  basically i want to ask that  when we are doing a project  do we use it as per scenario or both can do same thing ..

Answer (score 3):

```
Strings  words="These are sample words";
```

doesn't compile. There is no **Strings** type available in java.

You might be referring

```
String  words="These are sample words";
```

The difference between above and array is, above is single `String`. `String[]` will be used to store multiple **String**s

Answer (score 2):

The first line declares and initializes an array of `String` objects, while the second one, once you fix the compilation error (Strings should be `String`) declares and initializes a single `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare var with lowerCamelCase.

```
String [] wordsArray = {"first", "Second"..};
String  words = "These are sample words";
```